# How to clear Buefy input after event (VueJS)?

Tags: input, vue.js, bulma, buefy

I am trying to clear Buefy input with an event but nothing is happening. However this code work with basic input.

Here is my HTML:

```
<b-field>
  <b-input
    id="itemForm"
    placeholder="label"
    @keyup.enter.native="addItem">
  </b-input>
</b-field>
```

Here is my script:

```
methods: {
  addItem () {
    var input = document.getElementById('itemForm')

    if (input.value !== '') {
      this.items.push({
        name: input.value
      })
      input.value = ''
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried, and i am not sure but the only way to use `@keyup.enter` using buefy is: `@keyup.native.enter`

However i think you want something like this: [see it in action](https://codepen.io/Roland1993/pen/qKZbYa?editors=1010)

```
<div id="app" class="container">

  <ul>
    <li v-for="section in sections" :key="section.id">
      {{section.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>

    <section >
        <b-field label="Name">
            <b-input v-model.trim="name" @keyup.native.enter="addItem()" placeholder="Write and press enter"></b-input>
        </b-field>
    </section>

</div>
```

And the script:

```
Vue.use(Buefy.default)


    const example = {
        data() {
            return {
              sections: [],
              name: ''
            }
        },
      methods: {
        addItem () {
          this.sections.push({
            name: this.name,
            id: Date.now()
          })

          this.name = ''
        }
      }
    }


const app = new Vue(example)

app.$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Thanks, it works with `v-model.trim` to clear input. And `@keyup.enter.native` also work with buefy but I don't what's difference between `@keyup.native.enter`

Comment: If you have a look at API of buefy input at events tab you will see how to use events.Though,i suggest you to use vuetify it is more easier,flexible and complete.